# Set tooltip on a plottablejs linegraph from Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, plottable

I got a angular directive that displays a plottable line graph. But I need to set tooltips whit the value when the cursor hovers the line im plotting.

I got something like this:

```
var plot = new Plottable.Plots.Line()
   .addDataset(ds)
   .x(project_x, xScale)
   .y(project_y, yScale)
   .attr('stroke', function(d) { return label; }, colorScale);
```

and renders with

```
var svgElem = elem.find('svg')[0];
plot.renderTo(svgElem);
```

That works greate :) and then I tries to add some tooltips from this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gv1xsnkr/

```
// Initializing tooltip anchor
var tooltipAnchorSelection = plot.foreground().append("circle").attr({
  r: 3,
  opacity: 0
});
```

In the example they are using jquery, I dont want to import jquery just for this

```
var tooltipAnchor = $(tooltipAnchorSelection.node());
tooltipAnchor.tooltip({
  animation: false,
  container: "body",
  placement: "auto",
  title: "text",
  trigger: "manual"
});
```

So I tries to do it like this

```
var tooltipAnchor = document.querySelectorAll(tooltipAnchorSelection.node().nodeName);
```

But I get an error on

```
tooltipAnchor.tooltip({ ... });
```

angular.js:14516 TypeError: tooltipAnchor.tooltip is not a function

Anyone got a clue hot to do this?

Comment: I have the same Problem; the issue is that tooltip is not a function of jQuery, but of bootstrap - so you have to Import both. I still have Problems, that's why I won't post this as an answer, but my Problems now are because of typescript; the tooltip-function is now correctoly resolved to the bootstrap.js-file

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Vue.js, not Angular, but the problem sounds very similar. It was a problem of importing the libraries in the correct order:

- First jquery (required by bootstrap)
- Then bootstrap

How are you packaging your app?

I used gulp, so the sequence that worked for me was to put the jquery script tag in `index.html` and `bootstrap = require('bootstrap')` in the vue component (you'd put it in the directive). Requiring in bootstrap should be all that's necessary - that will give you access to the `tooltip` function.